# Implement a bottom drawer that stretches up

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an iPhone app.

I've been looking everywhere for help on implementing a drawer that opens from the bottom using a tab, but also, that the drawer could be pulled above its final height, in a spring like action, and when the user lets go of the drawer it will fast jump to the full drawer size.

I don't know the professional term for this spring-like action (and this may be why I couldn't find an implementation online) so I'll try to describe it here.

The spring-like action I mean is kinda like the pull to refresh works, but opposite in 2 ways - first, it should be pulled from the bottom up, second, I want the drawer to be pulled to its full size, and if the user pulls it higher with its finger, it will bounce back to its original size once the user lets go of its finger. 
In another example, I mean for the spring-like action to mimic what happens when a user is trying to go forward of the last screen of the home screen in iOS - it stretches to the left, but once the user lets go of his grip, the view will fast return to its normal state.

Thanks for your help,
Dan.